# how do i check even or odd in postscript

Tags: math, stack, postscript, modulus

I'm trying to check if the number on the top of the stack is even or odd without affecting my stack because I'm using it in a recursive function. I also tried to double pop but this code still messes up the function.

```
dup 2 0 mod eq 
{ 0 0 0 setrgpcolor}
{0.6 0.6 0.6 setrgpcolor}ifelse
pop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the order of the arguments wrong. One step at a time (assuming the top stack number is `123`):

```
123
dup 2 0 mod eq
```

do `dup`:

```
123 123 2 0 mod eq
```

do `mod` on `2 0` (!)

```
123 123 --undefined-- eq
```

and the `eq` is too little, too late...

Swap the 2 operands to get the right result:

```
dup 2 mod 0 eq
{ .. number is even ..}
{ .. number is odd ..} ifelse
```

---

(Note:
Is `setrgpcolor` a typo, or is there really a color model named so?)